# iOS 14 Widget placeholder redaction size and positioning mismatch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, wwdc

I was going through the [WWDC 2020 Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10035) and I noticed that when they preview the widget placeholder in the video the redaction generates nicely. But whenever I preview or run the widget, the placeholder positioning is all wrong.

From the Apple WWDC video:

[image: Apple placeholder]

Mine:

[image: placeholder] [image: unredacted]

Notice the placeholder content goes past the bounds of the box.

One thing I did add was `.minimumFontScale(0.5)` to get `Text` elements to resize but this doesn't seem to matter for the placeholder. I assume there was some change in Xcode or SwiftUI since the Apple video was created that is causing this difference.

Is there a way to adjust the view or the placeholder so it displays nicely?